# mootools ajax request aborts sporadically (onFailure)

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, mootools

I have a javascript function called when the page loads. It just gets some user data through an ajax call and checks some checkboxes based on the user id's returned.

```
window.onload=function(){
    getBlockedUsers();
} 

function getBlockedUsers(){
  var deptID = $('deptID').value;
  var request_data = 'DeptID='+deptID;
  var req = new Request.JSON({
    url:'/ajax/getuserData.cfm',
    method: 'post',
    noCahe: true,
    data: request_data,
     onSuccess: function(response)
    {
      var jLength = response.json.length;
      for(i=0;i<jLength;i++){
        var user_id = response.json[i].id;
        if($('user_'+user_id)){
          $('user_'+user_id).checked = true;
        }
      }
    },
    onFailure: function (xhr)
    {
      alert('There was an error while trying to fetch data');
    },
    onException: function (xhr)
    {
      alert('There was an exception while trying to fetch data');
    }
  }).send();
}
```

I keep getting the alert in the onFailure() function for some reason and when I inspect the ajax call, it appears to be aborted. This does not happen all the time. Happens in IE9.

I had the function call within domReady but moved to onload thinking it would help but it's still the same. Any ideas on why this might be happening would really help.

Comment: Your ajax Request has no `data` being sent to server and no `.send()` in the Class. http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Request.JSON

Comment: My bad. missed it while copy, pasting the code. Update the code.

Comment: what is `deptID`? did you check that value is correct? Another thing, please add a `var` here `for(i=`. Also what do you get when you do `console.log(xhr);`?

Comment: Thank you Sergio. deptID is something that's stored in a hidden variable when the dom populates. I logged it's value and it seems to be correct. I did also do console.log(xhr) and see nothing there. Just shows 'xmlHttpResponse'

Comment: sounds like a server-side issue. try GET if supported, look at the logs and see if the service itself fails. `console.log(this, this.response);` and look at the headers, status etc, look at network tab and see the response. there is nothing wrong here - only thing you can do is set some sort of a retry count and re-invoke the fn if it fails. make sure you use the latest mootools. try w/o `Request.JSON` and via `Request()` alone and manually use `JSON.encode(this.reponse.text)`. ensure `$('deptID').value;` actually always is read correctly from the DOM.

Comment: Thank you Dimitar. Great suggestions! I'll try using a retry count if it fails.